# Map array of strings as object properties

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs

I have an array like so.

```
const array =["king", "henry", "died", "while", "drinking", "chocolate", "milk"]
```

And I have the following initial state

```
state = {
options:{}
}
```

If I want to map this array to my state and assign each indexes string as a property of `this.state.options` how would I go about doing that?

So end result would be like:

```
console.log(this.state.options)
```

> output: {king: null, henry:null, died:null, while:null, drinking:null, chocolate: null, milk:null}

I think it would be undefined after that instead of null... But any suggestions?

Comment: Why do you want to do this?

Comment: this *`If I want to map this array to my state and assign each indexes string as a property`* is not so clear, please expalin it more

Comment: @GabrielePetrioli, this is just an example lol... In my project I am pre-populating a few nested drop down menus...And this is logically to me the best way to do it. Each property is going to have an array of objects that contain the selection options. The nested objects in the array populate depending on the property in `options`. That's as clear as I can probably explain. I didn't want to over complicate this question.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

I believe you are rather looking for `reduce` and not `map`

```js
const array =["king", "henry", "died", "while", "drinking", "chocolate", "milk"];

const state = {
  options: array.reduce( (current, item) => {
      current[item] = null;
      return current;
    }, {})
};

console.log( state );
```

Answer (score 6):

You can use the `Object.fromEntries` function:

```
const array = [ "king", "henry", "died", "while", "drinking", "chocolate", "milk" ];
state = {
    options: Object.fromEntries(array.map(value => [ value, null ]))
};
```

Your user agent may not provide `Object.fromEntries` with its scripting host -- the function is part of ECMAScript 2019 aka the 10th edition -- but you can use a stand-in until it does:

```
if(!Object.fromEntries)
    Object.fromEntries = entries => entries.reduce((result, entry) => (result[entry[0]] = entry[1], result), {});
```

I prefer to use parts of language or API that I expect to become available broadly later, by providing a stand-in implementation until such time these become available, at which time the code will, without any modifications, use the native implementation automatically (the above is evidently a conditional stand-in a or *polyfill* as it is also called).

Comment: `Object.fromEntries` has practically **zero** support (other than Firefox) so it should not be a viable solution really. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/fromEntries

Comment: Are we making assumptions about user agents now? I don't see any mention of one in the question. This is the forward compatible solution, and one can and *should* provide an implementation if the runtime does not provide one. In fact, I will pen one up and put it in the answer.

Comment: Sure do so so then it would make sense. Otherwise it is an assumption on your end that OP would have to jump through hoops to get your solution to work. If you provide all the needed steps then it would make sense I would agree.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this step by step :

```
const array =["king", "henry", "died", "while", "drinking", "chocolate", "milk"];

// We make a new options object which will be filled with the array's key / values
const options = {};

// Iterate through the array and fill the object
for ( let i = 0 ; i < array.length ; i++ ) {
    options[array[i]] = null
}

// At this point options === { "kind": null, "henry": null ... }

this.setState( { options } );
```

You can go further and simplify it :

```
// Check reduce at MDN https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce
const options = array.reduce( ( result, key ) => {
   result[key] = null;
   return result;
}, {} );

this.setState( { options } );
```

Or even better

```
this.setState( {
    options: array.reduce( ( result, key ) => Object.assign( result, {
        [key]: null
    } ), {} );
} );
```

Answer (score 0):

You could just do the following:

```js
const array =["king", "henry", "died", "while", "drinking", "chocolate", "milk"];
const state = {options: {}};
array.forEach((e, i) => state.options[e] = i);
```

Comment: shouldn't use `map ` if you aren't going to use the return value, favor `forEach` instead

Answer (score 0):

With [`Array.reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) you can do this:

```js
const data = ["king", "henry", "died", "while", "drinking", "chocolate", "milk"]

const state = { options: data.reduce((a,c) => (a[c] = null, a), {}) }

console.log(state)
```

This approach and the `Array.forEach` one make the most sense really since you do only one loop to get your object decorated. Otherwise you have to do **two or more** which is obviously not very efficient (In the cases of `Object.assign`/`Object.fromEntries` + `Array.map`)

Answer (score 0):

You could map single objects and assign all objects to a single object.

```js
const
    array = ["king", "henry", "died", "while", "drinking", "chocolate", "milk"],
    state = { options: Object.assign(...array.map(k => ({ [k]: null }))) };

console.log(state);
```

Answer (score 0):

Most of the above options look like a nice approach. I needed some similar functionality (converting 2d array to obj.key:val) today and was trying to use Object.fromEntities, but realized it was Firefox only as Akrion stated.

This is the solution I used.

```
var array = ["king", "henry", "died", "while", "drinking", "chocolate", "milk"];

function objFromArray(arr){
    var obj = {};
    arr.forEach(row=>{
        Object.defineProperty(obj, row,{
        value: null,
        writable: true
        });
    });
    return obj;
}
objFromArray(array);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this like it:

```
state = {
    options: {}
}

array =["king", "henry", "died", "while", "drinking", "chocolate", "milk"]

render(){
    return(
        <div>
            {this.array.forEach(value => this.state.options[value] = (this.array[value]=null))}
            {Object.keys(this.state.options).forEach(value => console.log(value,this.state.options[value]))}
        </div>
    ) 
}
```